# How to Get Backlinks Indexed

Tags: seo, backlinks

I have several backlinks in forum profiles.

1 How long does it take to get links indexed?

2 How to get all backlinks indexed in Google?

3 How to get backlinks indexed faster?

4 Are link indexers still relevant In 2018?

Thanks

Comment: "indexed" means that it is searchable via its words.  Links never get indexed.   Google may discover links and assign weight across them, but it doesn't index them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of this is proprietary info, so I can only speak from experience. Links get indexed fairly fast, as often as the site gets crawled and it finds the links. It has to be able to find the links.

If you have a link on a profile, for instance:

Does the profile need a login to get viewed? This may block a crawler.

Is there a page with all the members, new members, or active members. A crawler can find it this way.

A crawler can find it through a post or thread, when there is a link back to the profile.

Then, it depends on whether the engine counts these links. It's all proprietary.